# Jquery- Get the value of first td in table

Tags: jquery, select, html-table

I am trying to get the value of first td in each tr when a users clicks "click".

The result below will output aa ,ee or ii. I was thinking about using closest('tr').. but it always output "Object object". Not sure what to do on this one.

My html is

```
 <table>
   <tr>
      <td>aa</td>
      <td>bb</td>
      <td>cc</td>
      <td>dd</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="hit">click</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>ee</td>
      <td>ff</td>
      <td>gg</td>
      <td>hh</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="hit">click</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>ii</td>
      <td>jj</td>
      <td>kk</td>
      <td>ll</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="hit">click</a></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Jquery

```
$(".hit").click(function(){

 var value=$(this).// not sure what to do here

 alert(value)  ;

});
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
$(this).parent().siblings(":first").text()
```

`parent` gives you the `<td>` around the link,

`siblings` gives all the `<td>` tags in that `<tr>`,

`:first` gives the first matched element in the set.

`text()` gives the contents of the tag.

Comment: Helped me too! I was struggling to get the text from the first td and then found this little gem! Nice!

Answer (score 46):

This should work:

```
$(".hit").click(function(){    
   var value=$(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();
   alert(value);    
});
```

**Explanation:**

- [`.closest('tr')`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) gets the *nearest* ancestor that is a `<tr>` element (so in this case the row where the `<a>` element is in).
- [`.children('td:first')`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) gets all the children of this element, but with the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector we reduce it to the first `<td>` element.
- [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) gets the text inside the element

---

As you can see from the other answers, there is more than only one way to do this.

Comment: You all give correct answers! Since you already have 16K and Tesserex replied me first. I will give the accepted answer to Tesserex. Thanks a lot! +1 to u all.

Comment: ".children('td:first')" just what I needed.

Answer (score 13):

In the specific case above, you could do parent/child juggling.

```
$(this).parents("tr").children("td:first").text()
```

Comment: `closest` only looks for ancestors of the current element. Your second example would not work. And your first example does not work either because `parent()` only traverses on level up in the DOM hierarchy (you maybe mean `parents()`).

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".hit").click(function(){
   var values = [];
   var table = $(this).closest("table");
   table.find("tr").each(function() {
      values.push($(this).find("td:first").html());
   });

   alert(values);    
});
```

You should avoid `$(".hit")` it's really inefficient. Try using event delegation instead.

Comment: I think the OP wants to get the value of the first cell in the current row, not all rows.

Answer (score 3):

Install firebug and use `console.log` instead of `alert`. Then you will see the exact element your accessing.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get all td's inside tr without defining id for them, you can use the code below :

```
var items = new Array();

$('#TABLE_ID td:nth-child(1)').each(function () {
      items.push($(this).html());
});
```

The code above will add all first cells inside the Table into an Array variable.

you can change **nth-child(1)** which means the first cell to any cell number you need.

hope this code helps you.