# Get first TD of THIS row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Fairly easy yet i did not find how to do this online.

I want the first TD of the this element (row)

```
$(document).on("click", "#posTable tr", function() { 

    alert($(this).('td:first').text());

});
```

i tried:

```
alert($(this).('td:first').text());
alert($('td:first', $(this).parents('tr')).text()));
```

Comment: $(this).find('td:first')

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery- Get the value of first td in table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931234/jquery-get-the-value-of-first-td-in-table)

Answer (score 7):

You need to use [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the first td in the given row. You can also pass `this` in selector as a context.

Using [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
alert($(this).find('td:first').text());
```

Using [jQuery( selector [, context ] )](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context)

```
alert($('td:first', this).text());
```

Comment: can you provide some reference ( more examples ) of how to use context as use here.

Comment: That's great! is there something like W3C schools for this? i fail to find any simple information about things like these.. thanks!!

Comment: @PHPnooblet [You don't want "something like W3Schools" for anything!](http://www.w3fools.com/)