# Cannot get value of a first TD in current row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My requirement is to have 3 check-boxes in each table row, and once the checkbox is checked, it will create a hidden input with the value corresponding to the first `<td>` of THAT particular row.

Here is a sample row:

```
<tr>
    <td>user1</td>
    <td>768.51</td>
    <td>4,680</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0%</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name=">1 year and <=2 years[]" onclick="createUserNameInput()"></td>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>0.00%</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name=">2 years and <=3 years[]" onclick="createUserNameInput()"></td>
    <td>768.51</td>
    <td>100.00%</td>
    <td>4,677</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="> 3 years[]" onclick="createUserNameInput()"></td>
</tr>
```

Once any of the 3 check-boxes are checked, this hidden input should be created. If 3 are checked, 3 inputs should be created. `<value>` of these inputs should equal the value of first `<td>` in **THIS** row, which is `user1`. Here is how I am trying to implement it (code is inconsistent but I just need to get it working first):

```
<script>
    function createUserNameInput() {
        // var input = document.createElement("input");
        // input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        // input.setAttribute("name", "user");
        // input.setAttribute("value", $(this).parent().siblings(":first").text()); // VALUE IS EMPTY
        // document.getElementById("main-form").appendChild(input);

        alert($(this).parent().siblings(":first").text()); // VALUE IS EMPTY
    }
</script>
```

I have referenced these previous posts but none of those solutions work for me. When I run `alert()`, value is empty - nothing is displayed:

1. [Get first TD of THIS row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952781/get-first-td-of-this-row?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. [Jquery- Get the value of first td in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931234/jquery-get-the-value-of-first-td-in-table?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Who can help? If it can be done without jQuery, even more amazing!

Comment: Can you try `.siblings("td:first")`?

Comment: Wait isn't the parent of the input field your `td` tag? So don't you need two `parent()` methods?

Comment: @Dominik `alert($(this).parent().siblings("td:first").text());` did not work either. `parent()` is the `<td>` around my checkbox I believe

Comment: ok so can you try `$(this).parent().parent().siblings("td:first").text();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have to pass the object to the function you are calling:

   `onclick="createUserNameInput(this)"`
2. Convert the DOM object to jQuery object you retrieve.

   `createUserNameInput(e)` and `$(e).parent()...`

```js
function createUserNameInput(e) {
  // var input = document.createElement("input");
  // input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
  // input.setAttribute("name", "user");
  // input.setAttribute("value", $(this).parent().siblings(":first").text()); // VALUE IS EMPTY
  // document.getElementById("main-form").appendChild(input);

  alert($(e).parent().siblings(":first").text()); // VALUE IS NOT EMPTY NOW!
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>user1</td>
    <td>768.51</td>
    <td>4,680</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0%</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name=">1 year and <=2 years[]" onclick="createUserNameInput(this)"></td>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>0.00%</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name=">2 years and <=3 years[]" onclick="createUserNameInput(this)"></td>
    <td>768.51</td>
    <td>100.00%</td>
    <td>4,677</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="> 3 years[]" onclick="createUserNameInput(this)"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! I marked yours as an accepted answer since you have lower rating and answered first before Mamun did.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is, you are not passing `this` into the function. Pass `this` from the function call in the element so that you can refer that inside the function body.

```js
function createUserNameInput(el) {
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
  
  input.setAttribute("name", "user");
  input.setAttribute("value", $(el).parent().siblings(":first").text()); // VALUE IS EMPTY
  document.getElementById("main-form").appendChild(input);

  alert($(el).parent().siblings("td:first").text()); // VALUE IS EMPTY
  console.log('Hidden field value:',$('#main-form input[name=user]').val())
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-form"></div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>user1</td>
    <td>768.51</td>
    <td>4,680</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0%</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name=">1 year and <=2 years[]" onclick="createUserNameInput(this)"></td>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>0.00%</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name=">2 years and <=3 years[]" onclick="createUserNameInput(this)"></td>
    <td>768.51</td>
    <td>100.00%</td>
    <td>4,677</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="> 3 years[]" onclick="createUserNameInput(this)"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I accepted Chaska's answer simply because he answered first and he has lower rating as well. Your solution works as good as his. Thank you

Comment: How can I make _logical_ connection now between that checkbox and hidden input that I created? Actually, connection between hidden input's `value`, which is that first `<td>` and the `name` of a checkbox? What would you suggest?

Comment: @tera_789, the hidden input should be created in the `main-form` with the value. There should not be any problem.

Comment: Oh yeah it is. What I meant is this: there are **3** check-boxes for **each** user = 1 hidden input's `value` (username) should correspond to one of the checkbox's `name`. If I have 50 check-boxes checked, how do I connect them correctly among each other?

Comment: @tera_789, though the issue is not quite clear, you can set the name of checkbox  as well with the `td` text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179957/discussion-between-tera-789-and-mamun).

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the click event on the checkbox elements like,

```js
$(function(){
  $('.users').on('click',':checkbox',function(){
        // var input = document.createElement("input");
        // input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        // input.setAttribute("name", "user");
        // input.setAttribute("value", $(this).parent().siblings(":first").text()); // VALUE IS EMPTY
        // document.getElementById("main-form").appendChild(input);

        var tr = $(this).closest('tr')
console.log(tr.children("td:first").text(),'total checked = '+ tr.find(':checkbox:checked').length); // VALUE IS EMPTY
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="users">
<tr>
    <td>user1</td>
    <td>768.51</td>
    <td>4,680</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0%</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="1"></td>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>0.00%</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="2"></td>
    <td>768.51</td>
    <td>100.00%</td>
    <td>4,677</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="3"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Can you just pass to the function like this:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name=">1 year and <=2 years[]" onclick="createUserNameInput('user1')"></td>
```

---

And get like this:

```
<script>
    function createUserNameInput(value) {
        console.log(value);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest('tr').find("td:first").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this way, getting the parent node until the table and get the first child element

```
$(e).parentsUntil('table').find('td:first').text()
```