# How to get the PHP table values in jQuery when click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my table

http://postimg.org/image/vb9du3ikl/

All i want to do is when i click "CLICK HERE" i will get the LOAN ID value for example when i click "CLICK HERE" on the first row i will get 201410000account-00002. I've been searching the web not still the codes does't work :( i've been trying to figure this out for a week now :( please help codes guru

Here is my php to generate the table

```
$myquery="select loan.loanid,loanamount,interest,totalamount,duedate,paymenttype,remarks from loan,member,account where loan.accountid=account.accountid and account.memberid=member.memberid and account.memberid='".$mid."'";
    $results=mysql_query($myquery);


    echo "<table  id='tableID'  border='1' align='center'>";
    echo "<tr  style='background-color:#F60;color:white' align='center'><td>Loan ID</td><td>Loan Amount</td><td>Interest</td><td>Total Loan</td><td>Due Date</td><td>Payment type</td><td>Status</td><td>Loan Info</td></tr>";

    while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($results))
    {


            if($rs['remarks']=='done')
            {

                        echo"<td align='center' > ".$rs['loanid']."</td>";
                        echo"<td align='center'>".number_format($rs['loanamount'], 2, '.', ',')."</td>";
                        echo"<td align='center'>".number_format($rs['interest'], 2, '.', ',')."</td>";
                        echo"<td align='center'>".number_format($rs['totalamount'], 2, '.', ',')."</td>";
                        echo"<td align='center' > ".$rs['duedate']."</td>";
                        echo"<td align='center' > ".$rs['paymenttype']."</td>";
                        echo"<td align='center' >Fully Paid</td>";
                        print"<td style='color:red' align='center' onClick='loadXMLDoc()'  > <a>CLICK HERE</a></td>";
                        $loanID=$rs['loanid'];
                        echo "<tr>";    

            }else{

                        echo"<td align='center' > ".$rs['loanid']."</td>";
                        echo"<td align='center'>".number_format($rs['loanamount'], 2, '.', ',')."</td>";
                        echo"<td align='center'>".number_format($rs['interest'], 2, '.', ',')."</td>";
                        echo"<td align='center'>".number_format($rs['totalamount'], 2, '.', ',')."</td>";
                        echo"<td align='center' > ".$rs['duedate']."</td>";
                        echo"<td align='center' > ".$rs['paymenttype']."</td>";
                        echo"<td  style='color:red'align='center'   >On Going</td>";
                        print"<td style='color:red' align='center'><a href='index.php'>CLICK HERE</a></td>";
                        $loanID=$rs['loanid'];
                        echo "<tr>";                                            
                }                                       
    }
    echo "</table>";

    ?>
```

i tried this jq earlier but it does't work :(

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('tr').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        var selectedTd = $(this).children('td:first-child').text();
        alert(selectedTd);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery- Get the value of first td in table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931234/jquery-get-the-value-of-first-td-in-table)

Answer (score 0):

As i see you don't have refrenced the jquery library before your script and you need to bind event on `tr` element like this but in doc ready block:

```
$(function(){
   $('tr').click(function() {
      var selectedTd = $(this).find('td:first-child').text();
      alert(selectedTd);
   });
});
```

---

and if you are adding the `trs` through ajax then you need to user event delegation:

```
$('closestStaticParent').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var selectedTd = $(this).find('td:first-child').text();
    alert(selectedTd);
});
```

Here *closestStaticParent* is the dom node which was available when the DOM loaded before ajax call(*if any*).

---

So you need to include library first:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function(){
     $('tr').click(function() {
       var selectedTd = $(this).find('td:first-child').text();
       alert(selectedTd);
     });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you included jQuery library?

Comment: Am so sorry to ask this question but what u mean by "Have you included jQuery library?" am very new to this

Comment: If you use jquery code then you need to put jQuery library before you execute your custom jQuery code. You can find the library here:http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: You can check the with addding the library first. see the edit.

Comment: last question before you go hehe how can i save into a variable so i can call it later

Comment: You can declare a global var and you can update the value of it and use it anywhere in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

First load the jQuery library:

(using Google CDN here)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then add this script to do the `onclick` functionality:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('td').click(function() {
        var selectedTd = $(this).parent().find("td:first-child").text();
        alert(selectedTd);
    });
  });        
</script>
```

You need to add your event lintener inside `$(document).ready()`. You dont need the `.each()` loop. `.click()` will apply to all `td` elements.

Comment: OP has not loaded jquery library so this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your javascript action listener is incorrect. You should use something like this:

```
$(document).on('click','tr', function(){
    var selectedTd = $(this).children('td:first-child').text();
    alert(selectedTd);
});
```

Make sure the listener is between the `script` tags and you includes the jQuery libary.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).on('click','tr', function(){
        var selectedTd = $(this).children('td:first-child').text();
        alert(selectedTd);
    });

</script>
```

Your second problem is your HTML is incorrect to. You need to put the `td` elements in a `tr` tag. Try the PHP code below instead of your current "table creator" code.

```
if($rs['remarks']=='done')
{

            echo"<tr>";
            echo"<td align='center' > ".$rs['loanid']."</td>";
            echo"<td align='center'>".number_format($rs['loanamount'], 2, '.', ',')."</td>";
            echo"<td align='center'>".number_format($rs['interest'], 2, '.', ',')."</td>";
            echo"<td align='center'>".number_format($rs['totalamount'], 2, '.', ',')."</td>";
            echo"<td align='center' > ".$rs['duedate']."</td>";
            echo"<td align='center' > ".$rs['paymenttype']."</td>";
            echo"<td align='center' >Fully Paid</td>";
            print"<td style='color:red' align='center' onClick='loadXMLDoc()'  > <a>CLICK HERE</a></td>";
            $loanID=$rs['loanid'];
            echo "</tr>";    

}else{

            echo "<tr>";                                            
            echo"<td align='center' > ".$rs['loanid']."</td>";
            echo"<td align='center'>".number_format($rs['loanamount'], 2, '.', ',')."</td>";
            echo"<td align='center'>".number_format($rs['interest'], 2, '.', ',')."</td>";
            echo"<td align='center'>".number_format($rs['totalamount'], 2, '.', ',')."</td>";
            echo"<td align='center' > ".$rs['duedate']."</td>";
            echo"<td align='center' > ".$rs['paymenttype']."</td>";
            echo"<td  style='color:red'align='center'   >On Going</td>";
            print"<td style='color:red' align='center'><a href='index.php'>CLICK HERE</a></td>";
            $loanID=$rs['loanid'];
            echo "</tr>";                                            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your jquery statement is all right, if you click on 'tr',but if you click on anchor the page will be reloaded
if you still want to click the anchor, your code should like this:

```
$('tr a').click(function(e) {
    e.prenventDefault();
    var selectedTd = $(this).parent().find('td:first-child').text();
    alert(selectedTd);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you simply call your loadXMLDoc() function as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc(loanid){
alert(loanid);
}
</script>
```

And hence your "td" will be

```
echo "<td style='color:red' align='center' onClick='loadXMLDoc(".$rs['loanid'].")'  > <a>CLICK HERE</a></td>";
```